# bootstrap блоки с изображениями и подписью сверху

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как с помощью Bootstrap 3, сделать структуру из 5 колонок с изображениями и с заголовком сверху, как на скриншоте?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/full/QKWzgg/  это не bootstrap

Comment: по поводу 5 колонок - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: @Geyan ну с bootstrap тоже можно

Comment: @Nikita Smith я знаю но ни когда не не любил его,  пишу сам всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать пять двух-колоночных столбцов и добавить первому из них [смещение на одну колонку](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).

```css
.five-blocks .text {
  background: #fde;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
.five-blocks img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid five-blocks">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"><div class="text">Text</div><img src="//placehold.it/600x300/c69/fff/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="text">Text</div><img src="//placehold.it/600x300/c69/fff/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="text">Text</div><img src="//placehold.it/600x300/c69/fff/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="text">Text</div><img src="//placehold.it/600x300/c69/fff/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="text">Text</div><img src="//placehold.it/600x300/c69/fff/?text=Photo" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю что вам для этого потребуется `bootstrap`. Если использовать его колонки, то между карточками услуг будет оставаться лишнее пустое место. Я бы сделал их `inline-block` с расстоянием между буквами сколько-то `px` (чтобы задать пустое пространство между ними) либо с `float-left` и отступом по сторонам.

Посмотрите пример с `float-left` (тут понадобится `clearfix hack`, в бутстрапе он уже встроен). Возможно это вам подойдет.

```css
.services {
  clear: both;
}
.services:before,
.services:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
}
.services:after {
  clear: both;
}
.service-card {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  color: #777;
}
.service-card > h4,
.service-card > p {
  margin: 5px 2px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.service-card > h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 16px;
}
.service-card > p {
  height: 45px;
}
.service-card > img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <div class="service-card">
    <h4>
      Caption 1
    </h4>
    <p>
      Some text description goes here goes here
    </p>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/130x80" />
  </div>
  <div class="service-card">
    <h4>
      Caption 2
    </h4>
    <p>
      Some text description goes here
    </p>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/130x80" />
  </div>
  <div class="service-card">
    <h4>
      Caption 3
    </h4>
    <p>
      Some text description goes here
    </p>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/130x80" />
  </div>
  <div class="service-card">
    <h4>
      Caption 4
    </h4>
    <p>
      Some text description goes here goes here goes here here
    </p>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/130x80" />
  </div>
  <div class="service-card">
    <h4>
      Caption 4
    </h4>
    <p>
      Some text description goes here goes here goes here here
    </p>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/130x80" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Тут задаю высоту для заголовка и для подзаголовка, чтобы карточки имели одинаковую высоту. Если у вас картинки больше, чем требуется то задайте им `img-responsive` из бутстрапа и задайте требуемую ширину карточки.